# Simple XML cannot access name attribute successfully

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an object that spits out this if i run this code:

```
print_r($xml->config->Exported->stats->children() );

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Stat] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Name
                            [abrev] => 
                            [format] => 2
                        )
                )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Hands
                            [abrev] => H:
                            [format] => 0
                        )
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => V.total
                            [abrev] => V:
                            [format] => 0
                        )
                )
          )
```

My code is:

```
foreach($xml->config->Exported->stats->children() as $node){

    echo $node . "<br />";
    switch ( $node->getName() )
    {
        case 'Stat':
        $stat_name = (string)$node['name'];
        echo $stat_name . " | ";
        break;
        case 'New_Line':
        echo '<hr />';
    break;
    }
```

Which should return something like this:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/hMvg9W

While that does work my code does not. Does the simple xml output differ from the standard xml output in the example that works, any idea how i tweak this to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is case sensitive. "Name" and "name" are different qualified names.